# Cargar Tabla desde Excel a Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Tengo una tabla en Excel cuyo nombre es table_1, desde VBA puedo utilizar la función getTable para iterar sobre su contenido, sin embargo no he sido capaz de encontrar una funcionalidad similar en Python. Es posible?

En general deseo cargar a Python un rango que esté definido en el administrador de nombres, sin entrar a definir en qué hoja está, ni entre que filas o columnas se encuentra.

edit: lo que busco es algo similar a [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896209/read-values-from-named-ranges-with-openpyxl), sin embargo, no he sido capaz de hacerlo funcionar todavia

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente se ocupa pandas, por ejemplo

```
from pandas import read_excel

my_sheet = 'Hoja_1' # Nombre de la hoja 
file_name = 'nombre_del_archivo.xlsx' # Nombre del archivo
df = read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = my_sheet)
print(df.head())
```

EL objeto df es la planilla de excel que necesitas, y si sheet_name es None, entonces te devolvera un diccionario con todas las hojas.